# How to change status bar color when app is in list of oppened apps

Tags: ionic3

I already change the status bar color of my app, but when I click in list of openned apps (Android) the status bar color is default(Blue).
How to fix this?

[image discribing what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5lk0.jpg)

Comment: You cannot change the status bar color outside of your app.

Comment: I didn't know the name of the component. The real name is Header Color in mult tasking. And I found it in ionic native https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/header-color

Comment: @AilsondaCruz Feel free to add your latest comment as an answer and accept it since that's exactly how to solve your question.

Comment: You are talking about the header color, not the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know the name of the component. The real name is Header Color in mult tasking. And I found it in ionic native [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/header-color/)